# How to get the items of an array returned from a database in ionic 3

Tags: arrays, object, ionic-framework

I want to return every element from this array and set it to a string variable inside ionic 3 ts file : 0: {Name: "s", DateOfBirth: "s", Adress: "s", Telephone: "s"}
0: {Name: "s", DateOfBirth: "s", Adress: "s", Telephone: "s"}
**proto**: Objectlength: 1
**proto**: Array(0)

My ionic 3 code is :

```
   public items : any =[];
   PatientName:string;

   public Name:string;
   public DateOfBirth:string;
   public Adress:string;
   public Telephone:string;


   public name:string;
   public dateOfBirth:string;
   public adress:string;
   public telephone:string;


  constructor(public http:Http,public navCtrl: NavController, public 
  navParams: NavParams) {
  this.PatientName=navParams.get('Username');
    }


    load(){




    this.http.get('http://localhost:10080/testdb/PatientProfile.php?
    Patientname='+this.PatientName)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => 
    {
       this.items = data; 

        this.DateOfBirth=this.items.DateOfBirth;
        this.Adress=this.items.Adress;
        this.Telephone=this.items.Telephone;
        console.log(data);        
    });









    }

ionViewDidLoad() {

this.PatientName=this.navParams.get('Username');
console.log(this.PatientName);
console.log('ionViewDidLoad PatientInfoPage');
this.load();
```

}

AND this is the .html file"

```
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating color="primary">Name</ion-label>


    <ion-input 
       type="text" 


       [(ngModel)]="Name" value="{{name}}"></ion-input>



      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating color="primary">Date Of Birth</ion-label>


    <ion-input 
       type="text" 


       [(ngModel)]="DateOfBirth" value="{{dateOfBirth}}"></ion-input>

    </ion-item>

    <ion-item> 
    <ion-label floating color="primary">Adress</ion-label>


    <ion-input 
       type="text" 


       [(ngModel)]="Adress" value="{{adress}}"></ion-input>

      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label floating color="primary">Telephone Number</ion-label>


    <ion-input 
       type="text" 


       [(ngModel)]="Telephone" value="{{telephone}}"></ion-input>


    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Couple of things here. You have defined items as an array. If so you can't access its properties like this.items.Name. You have to loop through it. If need to get first item then you can do this.item[0].Name. Also is the api returning an array? From the example it doesn't seems like that..

Comment: It is returning an object i guess i will try this.items[0] , looping throw it didn’t work